# Why does my <img> resize when I use show() and hide()?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Maybe this is not the smartest way to implement a language switcher.

But I came up with this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.lang-switch').hover(
    function() {
      $('.lang-inactive').hide();
      $('.lang-active').show();
    }, function() {
      $('.lang-active').hide();
      $('.lang-inactive').show();
    }
  );
});
```

```css
#lang {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 18px;
  padding: 20px 0 15px 0;
}

#lang ul {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#lang li {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lang">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="images/lang_DE_active.png"
           alt="Deutsch"
           style="width:30px; height:18px"/>
    </li>
    <li class="lang-switch">
      <a href="EN_What.html">
        <img class="lang-inactive"
             src="images/lang_EN_inactive.png"
             alt="English"
             style="width:30px; height:18px"/>
        <img class="lang-active"
             style="display:none"
             src="images/lang_EN_active.png"
             alt="English"
             style="width:30px; height:18px"/>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What happens then is this (click to see the gif):

[The lang_EN_active.png resizes to its original PNG-size (100x60) while hovering.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cy423.gif)

[image]

Why is this happening? Can I prevent it? Or should I use a whole different way for the language switcher (e.g. declaring the hover in CSS)?

Comment: You should put all the styles in your stylesheet if you want to control them better. Your issue may be because of them being overriden by jQuery

Comment: The image has two style attributes. That's not allowed.

Comment: Damn! I haven't noticed!!! Haha, now that's easy, thank you very much. Works great now :)

Comment: You shouldn't use inline styles at all; put the style declarations in the CSS file.

Comment: Will do! Thank you very much.

Comment: Why all the trouble? You can make it gray scale in css en undo it in a css hover...

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I haven't been checking out the -webkit-filter stuff yet. Works way better and less code is always appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi i have check your code and i thing some css is overwrite your image style. SO simple way is use `!important`
I have also noticed that there are two `style` attribute in your `image` tag.

**Here is the code :**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.lang-switch').hover(
    function() {
      $('.lang-inactive').hide();
      $('.lang-active').show();
    }, function() {
      $('.lang-active').hide();
      $('.lang-inactive').show();
    }
  );
});
```

```css
#lang {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 18px;
  padding: 20px 0 15px 0;
}

#lang ul {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#lang li {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lang">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="images/lang_DE_active.png"
           alt="Deutsch"
           style="width:30px; height:18px"/>
    </li>
    <li class="lang-switch">
      <a href="EN_What.html">
        <img class="lang-inactive"
             src="images/lang_EN_inactive.png"
             alt="English"
             style="width:30px; height:18px"/>
        <img class="lang-active"
             src="images/lang_EN_active.png"
             alt="English"
             style="width:30px; height:18px; display:none"/>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Its a bad habbit to !important but its indeed a quick fix. A better quick fix is to use the selecter twice! Like this .test.test {width: 10px;} all the !important does is select the selector like 100 times. So this is beter! Less code in browser.

Comment: Thank you again, @BhavinSolanki
But actually, I will now discard all my jQuery and simply go for a CSS filter (saturate, grayscale).